# Difference between AMFChannel and pollingAMFChannel

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

I found an Adobe document that defines the amfChannel [Adobe amfChannel](https://flex.apache.org/asdoc/mx/messaging/channels/AMFChannel.html). Is there a big difference between amfChannel and pollingAMFChannel? FlashBuilder 4.7 does not provide any documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `AMFChannel` is a class of Flex-BlazeDS integration project not of Flashbuilder. So Flashbuilder documentation will not have information about it, I believe.
2. As per my understanding, There is no `pollingAMFchannel` which is different than AMFChannel.

Basically, there is only `AMFChannel` which is,
 `AMFChannel  -> NetConnectionChannel -> PollingChannel -> Channel -> flash.events.EventDispatcher`

If you are wondering about "my-amf" and "my-polling-amf" channels (usually found in services-config.xml in blazeds integration project) then they are just naming conventions used for different AMFChannels to keep things separated.

Comment: just can you tell me why we need more than channels to send data what i mean is i could not understand the word " To keep things separated " ??

Comment: It's mostly because of clean design. The same reason why do you need separate HashMaps to store key values for savingAccountsMap, checkingAccountsMap. [key=AccountId, value="Account Object"]. Both can be accomodated in a single map yet, we keep them in separate maps because we want to have clean separation between data.